# Default value of Autocomplete is undefined in MUI v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I have set the `defaultValue` prop in `Autocomplete` component of MUI v5 but the value is always `undefined`.

**Excerpt from my code**

```
const cars = [
  { label: "BMW", code: "Volkswagen" },
  { label: "Benz", code: "Mercedes" }
];

...

 const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      car: ""
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {}
  });

...
      <Autocomplete
        id="autocomplete"
        options={cars}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.code} - ${option.label}`}
        renderOption={(props, option) => (
          <Box component="li" {...props}>
            {option.code} - {option.label}
          </Box>
        )}
        defaultValue={`${cars[0].code} - ${cars[0].label}`}
        onChange={(e, value) => {
          formik.setFieldValue("car", `${value.code} - ${value.name}`);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            id="textField"
            name="cars"
            label="Cars"
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
            onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
            inputProps={{
              ...params.inputProps,
              autoComplete: "new-password"
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
```

I created a working example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-t74fg?file=/demo.js:757-1621). Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You got `undefined-undefined` because you have already described how the selected property should look like here:

```
getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.code} - ${option.label}`}
```

Therefore, you should pass to default option an object where it's possible to access `code` and `label` values.
Changing `defaultValue={cars[0]}` will help.

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-forked-so7qc?file=/demo.js:701-723)

Answer (score 0):

you can just use:

```
defaultValue={cars[0]}
```

[image: Edit autocomplete (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

when you use defaultValue with autocomplete you need set the param's name

```
defaultValue={{ label: cars?.label, code cars?.code }}
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is in
getOptionLabel prop you were not checking wheather *

> option?.code && option?.label

- is defined or not so because of this undefined was showing. so change line 23 of your code to

> getOptionLabel={(option) =>option.code && option.label ?
> `${option.code} - ${option.label}` : ''}